# Primary user approval required when payment send from paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have integrated "Adoptive Payment Method" Paypal in my work. But i want to admin approval required while payment deduct from all money. In Adaptive payment method user have submit $100 and if we pass parameter for primary and secondary user then paypal will auto deduct and submit in his both account. But i want admin(primary) email approval. Like if user have submit $100 then all money will submitted in primary user paypal account and when they approve for deduct now then commission will deduct from his account. This is possible in "Adoptive Payment Method" or please let me know how i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you cannot do this with "Adoptive Payment".

In Adoptive Payment, the dispatch can only be triggered once. In this transaction, user/PayPal/you/secondary are all participants.

In the flow you want (holding the money as primary account and then assign to secondary at another time), only user/PayPal/you are participants of payment transaction. This change the payment responsibility of your secondary, and most likely is not what you want.